# When to use "Porter à" and when "porter sur"?

Tags: usage, prépositions

Quand faut-il dire 'porter sur' et quand 'porter à' (quelque chose) ? Par example :

> Je vous remercie de l'intérêt que vous avez porté sur ma candidature.
> vs
> Je vous remercie de l'intérêt que vous avez porté à ma candidature.

Ibid.

> L'accent portait sur (ou à) ce point.

> Il faut porter une attention particulière au (ou sur le) debut du semestre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'usage est nuancé comme les constructions *porter à* et *prêter à* ([réf.](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/BDL/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3811)) sont différentes de celles de *porter sur.*  La différence, c'est la signification. Les locutions avec la préposition *à* s'emploient pour signifier « conduire » ou « pousser » quelqu'un  vers quelque chose un peu comme signifie la construction *faire faire*.

> La construction porter à, qui peut elle aussi être suivie d'un nom ou
> d'un verbe à l'infinitif, signifie « amener, inciter, pousser
> quelqu'un à ».
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Cet endroit porte à la sérénité.
> - Son expérience le porte à la prudence.
> - Les malheurs de Justine la portent à s'offrir de petits plaisirs.

> La construction prêter à, qui peut être suivie d'un nom ou d'un verbe à l'infinitif, signifie « donner lieu ou matière à, fournir l'occasion de ».

> - Ce passage du texte prête (ou porte) à confusion.
> - C'est le genre d'histoire qui porte (ou prête) à rire.

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/porter/62780) vérifie et donne des exemples suivants :

> Inciter quelqu'un à faire quelque chose, l'y pousser : Son tempérament le porte à l'indulgence.

et deux cas avec quelque chose sur quelque chose :

> Appliquer son attention, ses efforts sur quelque chose : Nous devons porter nos efforts sur ce point.

Par contre, la construction *porter sur* suivie d'un nom signifie *[concerner](https://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/porter%20sur/verbe)* ([CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter)) ou *traiter,* *toucher*.
Des exemples de [porter sur](https://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/porter+sur.html) :

> Le livre porte sur l'histoire de la ville.
>
>  Cette contestation politique porte sur la nouvelle loi.
>
>  
>  Cette étude doit porter sur les signes observés, notamment les phénomènes locaux.
>
>  Le débat devrait également porter sur les besoins des enfants. ([Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/porter+sur))

Answer (score 2):

Sur introduit le complément d’argument, alors que l’autre forme, avec « à » est plutôt utilisée dans tous les autres cas. Donc je crois que les formes sans parenthèses sont les formes les plus correctes.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a couple of examples?

Comment: Ex 1: La conférence d'aujourd'hui porte sur le concept d'algèbre de Hopf (complément d'argument). Ex 2: Hier J'ai porté un cadeau à mon père.

Comment: Merci ! So would be faulty to say La conférence d'aujourd'hui porte au concept d'algèbre de Hopf? (no native speaker:-)!)

Comment: Yes, I think it wouldn’t be correct.

Comment: Je suis de langue maternelle italienne et J’ai étudié la langue latine. Dans les deux langues citées le complètement d’argument existe bien et sert exactement pour décrire l’argument dont on parle. Soit en Italien qu’en Latin il est introduit par la préposition « de », (suivie du cas ablatif en Latin, mais pas en Italien où l’on a perdu la flexion). Je crois que ce complètement existe aussi bien en Français qu’en Italien ou en Latin, mais Je ne suis pas un linguiste. Voilà ce que Je peux vous dire là-dessus.

Comment: Je suis désolé pour la confusion entre la grammaire française et celle italienne ou latine, mais Je suis sûr qu’il doit y avoir une quelque relation entre elles.

Comment: Je ne se capitalise pas comme en anglais (Quand je suis = When I'm ...).

Answer (score 1):

Les éléments constitutifs du discours sont très variables, du moins en français. Une façon de résoudre la problématique serait de savoir si la préposition est dissociable du verbe.

#### CQFD;

> La préposition est dissociable du verbe parce que : **a)** elle peut avoir une connotation, **b)** le choix d'une préposition dépend de son rôle et **c)** du contexte. Comme dans la phrase *Je vous remercie **pour** l'intérêt que vous avez porté **à** ma candidature*. On choisit effectivement la préposition *pour* parce qu'***on adresse ses remerciements*** en indiquant la cause. On choisit la préposition ***à*** plutôt que ***sur*** car *ma candidature* évoque les sèmes de personne (moi) et de candidat (candidature) *sauf que* le locuteur s'exprime par rapport à lui-même mais également envers l'allocutaire.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you be more specific by giving a bit of examples of usage? I have seen sentences with both sur and à. When to use porter sur and when porter à?

Comment: Les deux sont des prépositions (*à* et *sur*) ; comment expliquer la différence ?

Answer (score 1):

On s'occupe d'abord du sens dans la première phrase proposée et dans  la dernière parce que la préposition qui convient est « à » dans les deux cas.

**I**

- Je vous remercie de l'intérêt que vous avez porté **à** ma candidature.

La définition du TLFi qui convient est la suivante : [**1re Section II. C. 1. a)**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter). Si on analyse la construction et que l'on détermine qu'elle est de la forme « **Qqn porte qqc à/sur qqc** » où le premier « qqc » est une attitude et que l'on remarque que le mot « intérêt » est souvent utilisé on a  un moyen de converger sur la définition et la préposition.

> **1re Section.** Empl. trans. Porter qqc./qqn
> **II.** − [Le procès implique, par lui-même, un déplacement d'un point à un autre de l'espace, ou une notion abstr. corresp.]
> **C.** − [Exprime l'idée gén. de procès actif, de manifestation active, dont la spécificité est définie par le compl. d'obj. dir. qui désigne une attitude, un comportement, une action ou un état résultatif, dont l'agent ou la cause directe (pers. ou chose) est désigné(e) par le suj. et dont l'obj. ou l'entité directement intéressé(e) est désigné(e) par un compl., parfois omis, introd. par une prép.]
> **1** Qqn porte qqc. (sentiment, attitude) à qqn/qqc.[Le compl. d'obj. dir. désigne un sentiment ou une attitude; le suj. désigne une pers.; le compl. introd. gén. par **à** désigne une pers. ou une chose et serait le compl. d'obj. dir. ou indir. du verbe corresp. au subst. compl. d'obj. dir. (lorsque ce verbe existe)] **Éprouver, manifester tel sentiment ou telle attitude à l'égard de quelqu'un/quelque chose.**
> **a)** [Le compl. d'obj. dir. est accompagné d'un art.]
> **[Porter se trouve dans une rel. déterminant le subst. accompagné seulement de l'art. déf.]**
>
> - [Mon coeur] ne m'a jamais trompé sur le degré d'intérêt qu'on me porte (Delacroix, Journal, 1823, p.37).
> - Il vint donc ce Maurice que j'admirais en aveugle, sur la foi de l'amitié que lui portait mon frère (Colette, Mais. Cl., 1922, p.164).

Quelques explications seront peut-être nécessaire pour mieux identifier les termes du dictionnaire.
**1re section** L'emploi est transitif ; ici il s'agit de porter qqc et non qqn ; ce qqc est « l'intérêt » représenté par « que ».
**II** Le procès implique une notion abstraite correspondante à la notion de déplacement dans l'espace et, évidemment pas un déplacement dans l'espace.
**C** La  spécificité du procès est définie par le cod (que), c'est à dire « intérêt » qui en est l'antécédent et ce mot (intérêt) désigne une attitude dont l'agent est le sujet « je », une personne ; l'objet de cette attitude, ou plutôt l'entité directement intéressée est désigné par le complément « ma candidature » introduit par une préposition (ici, « **à** »).
**1** Ceci n'est que la particularisation à qqc, excluant la possibilité « qqn » qui est portée à l'alinéa « 1re Section » et la stipulation que la préposition est « à ». Les autres éléments mentionnés ont déjà été déterminés. « chose et serait le compl. d'obj. dir. ou indir. du verbe corresp. au subst. compl. d'obj. dir. (lorsque ce verbe existe) » signifie que si un verbe existe pour « porter intérêt »,  alors « candidature » est cod de ce verbe dans la construction qui correspond; comme ce verbe existe (s'intéresser) la phrase devient « je vous remercie de vous intéresser à ma candidature ». Ce qui est en caractères gras est la définition, que l'on doit particulariser à « qqc ».
**a)** Le cod n'est pas  accompagné d'un article puisque le cod est « que » mais c'est pratiquement de cette situation dont il est question, comme on le voit au prochain alinéa.
**[Porter se trouve dans une rel. déterminant le subst. accompagné seulement de l'art. déf.]** "Porter" se trouve dans la relation « V + pronom cod (que) » et cette relation détermine bien un substantif avec un article défini, c'est à dire « l'intérêt ».

Ce qui est dit donc c'est « Je vous remercie de manifester de l'intérêt à l'égard de ma candidature ».

On utilise « à » lorsque « porter » doit signifier « **Éprouver, manifester tel sentiment ou telle attitude à l'égard de quelqu'un/quelque chose** ».

*Exemples*

- Le soin que vous portez **à** votre travail se remarque.
- Il  porte une telle  haine **à** ces travaux qu'on ne peut plus lui en parler.
- Elle  porte **à** cet ancien amis un mépris considérable et ne veut plus le voir.
- Ce patron  porte **à** ses employés le respect qu'il méritent.

**II**

*Note     Ci-dessous les remarques entre crochets en italique sont de user LPH.*

- Il faut porter une attention particulière **au**  début du semestre.

La définition est dans la même partie que pour la phrase précédente parce que la construction est similaire. le cod (attention) est une attitude, et il est accompagné d'un article, mais cette fois-ci, c'est un article indéfini (une). Le cas particulier est donc le suivant.

**− [Art. indéf. + déterm. particularisant]** On a bien un article indéfini (une) et un déterminatif particularisant (particulière) et ce cas doit être le bon.

> Porter une vive affection, un attachement véritable, une attention inquiète, une confiance aveugle, un dégoût extrême, une ardente dévotion, un grand/vif intérêt, un respect sincère, une grande sollicitude à qqn/qqc.
>
> - Tous ces gens-là **nous** portaient une haine d'autant plus terrible, qu'ils n'osaient la montrer tout de suite. (Erckm.-Chatr., Conscrit 1813, 1864, p.155) *[noter que la préposition ne parait pas en raison de la forme du complément, celle-ci étant un pronom.]*
> - Les femmes aussi (...) **me** portent des sentiments rien moins que tendres. (Verlaine, OEuvres compl., t.4, Mes hôp., 1891, p.344)  *[même remarque que ci-dessus]*
> - Albert portait une riche curiosité **aux** mythes qui ont bercé l'humanité dans sa longue histoire, il en recherchait avec passion la signification intime (Gracq, Argol, 1938, p.39)

Ce qui est dit est « **Il faut manifester de l'attention à l'égard du début du semestre.** ».

**III**

Pour la seconde phrase il n'y a aussi qu'une solution, mais cette fois-ci c'est « sur ».

> L'accent portait sur  ce point.

La définition du TLFi est [**2e section I. B. 1.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/porter).

**2eSection.** Empl. intrans.
**I.** − Porter sur [parfois contre, moins souvent une autre prép. introduisant un compl. de lieu]
**B.** − Au fig. Porter sur [parfois contre avec nuance d'hostilité, moins souvent une autre prép.]
**1.** [Le suj. désigne une action volontaire ou son résultat] **S'appliquer à, avoir pour objet ou pour objectif.**

> - Les impôts qui portent sur les denrées nécessaires elles-mêmes (Say, Écon. pol., 1832, p.532).
> - Nous touchons ici à l'essence même de la connaissance historique: quand elle porte à plein sur son objet, c'est-à-dire sur toute la richesse de la réalité humaine, elle n'est pas susceptible de cette accumulation de probabilité qui, théoriquement, pourrait conduire à une quasi-certitude (Marrou, Connaiss. hist., 1954, p.133).

On reconnait que le verbe est intransitif, donc il faut chercher dans la seconde section. On élimine « **II** » et « **III** » parce que « **II B fig.** (« Avoir un effet ou l'effet visé; faire son effet. ») et  « **III** » ne conviennent pas. Donc « **S'appliquer à, avoir pour objet ou pour objectif.** » est la définition.

Il faut dire « sur » **quand le sujet est qqc qui  a pour objectif le complément, qui s'applique au complément**.

*Exemples*

- Ce livre porte **sur** une question difficile. (*Ce livre s'applique à une question difficile. — Ce livre a pour objet une question difficile.*)
- Son explication porte **sur** les fondements de la théorie.
- Le refus de cette personne porte **sur** une question de principe.
- La loi porte **sur** un point obscur de parenté.